# Inverting integral transform with kernel $x^n$

Tags: functional-analysis, inverse-function, integral-transforms

I'm looking to find the inverse of

$$g(n)= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)x^n dx$$

I'm not sure if an inverse exists but i suspect the kernel is well behaved enough to have an inverse.If an inverse exists I'd like to know how I'd go about inverting this, I am only concerned with real functions here, $f(x)$ is real. $g(n)$ is also known for all real $n$.

I looked up fredholm integral equation but I'm not sure how I'd go about applying that here since i need a kernel something like.

$$(1-x)^n$$

Comment: What is the domain of your function $g$?, are there any assumptions on $f$?

Comment: @uniquesolution all real, i'm only concerned with real functions here. I'm looking to find an $$f(x)$$ given $$g(n)$$

Comment: for what set of $n$ do you know $g$? For all natural numbers? For all integers?

Comment: @uniquesolution for all reals, perhaps i should have used a different variable

Comment: Without assuming the domain of $f$ is complex(not what exactly OP wants to find), it will be Mellin transform and its inverse.

Comment: What is $x^n$ here when $x<0$ and $n$ is irrational?